# SQL Server concatenate procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, concatenation

I'm trying to learn how to use a concatenated procedure, but it doesn't return the result I want. Even when I use the command

```
EXEC SP_NAME_PROCEDURE NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

or using the right data.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_LISTA_PEDIDOS
    @Sdatainicio varchar(100),
    @Sdatafim varchar(100),
    @chaveBusca varchar(100),
    @TipoBusca varchar(100)
AS 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)

    SET @SQL += 'SELECT *,b.descricao as dscstatus,c.nome as cliente '

    SET @SQL += ' FROM pedidos   a with(nolock), '
    SET @SQL += ' pedidos_status b with(nolock), '
    SET @SQL += ' cadastro c with(nolock) '

    SET @SQL += ' WHERE '
    SET @SQL += ' a.status <> '''' and '
    SET @SQL += ' a.status=b.status and '
    SET @SQL += ' a.id_doc = c.id_doc '

    IF isnull(@chaveBusca,'')<>''
    BEGIN
        IF isnull(@TipoBusca,'') = 'PEDIDO'
           SET @SQL += ' and a.numped= '''+@chaveBusca+''''

        IF isnull(@TipoBusca,'') = 'CLIENTE'
           SET @SQL += ' and c.nome like '''+@chaveBusca+'%'''
    END

    IF not (isnull(@chavebusca,'')<>'' and isnull(@TipoBusca,'') = 'PEDIDO')
        SET @SQL += ' and data_inclusao BETWEEN '''+@Sdatainicio+''' AND '''+@Sdatafim+''''

    SELECT @SQL
```

Can you guys help me find out what's wrong?

Comment: "but it doesnt give me the result I want. " - well, what result did it give you, and what did it want? Note: what you have here is a sql-injection nightmare. You can actually use varadic parameters with `sp_executesql`. The final value of `@SQL` would be useful to help us debug

Comment: You haven't handled NULL for the first two parameters.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I'm new at this and really want to learn more. I'll keep an eye out for the procedures names. And about the results, i wanted it to give me the full table(without the WHERE clause) when I use NULL as a value.

Comment: This is like a laundry list of things you shouldn't do. I see other already mentioned the SP_ prefix and the NOLOCK hints. You are also using a very old join style. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Then there is the dynamic sql. Why??? There is no reason for dynamic sql here at all. And if you do use dynamic sql you need to parameterize it before bobby tables comes to visit. This is just awful from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You haven to checks for `NULL` values when concatenating strings because `NULL` + `string` is `NULL`.

For example, check your very first line:

[image]

it should be:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000) = ''
```

Also, you should add checks for the input parameters. For example:

```
ISNULL(@chaveBusca, '')
```

Comment: the only parameters i havent handled are the dates. Inicial date and final date. But thanks, it helped me a lot

Comment: i understand the reason you set @SQL varchar(100)='', but it still gives me the null table

Comment: in your question - show how you are executing the procedure

Answer (score 0):

Assign Initial Value to @SQL VARCHAR(8000)='', Because NULL+Value results to NULL.

And Instead of executing with NULL as input value you can set default value to NULL or '' (space) and execute without input value.

```
    EXEC SP_LISTA_PEDIDOS
```

Try this script.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE SP_LISTA_PEDIDOS
    -- EXEC SP_LISTA_PEDIDOS @Sdatainicio='Test1',@Sdatafim='Test2',@chaveBusca='Test3',@TipoBusca='Test4'
    @Sdatainicio varchar(100) ='',
    @Sdatafim varchar(100) ='',
    @chaveBusca varchar(100) ='',
    @TipoBusca varchar(100) =''

    AS 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)=''

    SET @SQL += 'SELECT *,b.descricao as dscstatus,c.nome as cliente '

    SET @SQL += ' FROM pedidos   a with(nolock), '
    SET @SQL += ' pedidos_status b with(nolock), '
    SET @SQL += ' cadastro c with(nolock) '

    SET @SQL += ' WHERE '
    SET @SQL += ' a.status <> '''' and '
    SET @SQL += ' a.status=b.status and '
    SET @SQL += ' a.id_doc = c.id_doc '


    IF isnull(@chaveBusca,'')<>''
     BEGIN

      IF isnull(@TipoBusca,'') = 'PEDIDO'
         SET @SQL += ' and a.numped= '''+@chaveBusca+''''

      IF isnull(@TipoBusca,'') = 'CLIENTE'
         SET @SQL += ' and c.nome like '''+@chaveBusca+'%'''
     END

    IF not (isnull(@chavebusca,'')<>'' and isnull(@TipoBusca,'') = 'PEDIDO')
        SET @SQL += ' and data_inclusao BETWEEN '''+@Sdatainicio+''' AND '''+@Sdatafim+''''

    SELECT @SQL
```

Comment: it still gives me the null table

Comment: I am getting result with and without parameter... did you altered the script?

Comment: yes.. and also added the null check for the first 2 parameters

Comment: Just execute the script int my post and share me the update.

Comment: It gives me a table 1x1 with this as value: SELECT *,b.descricao as dscstatus,c.nome as cliente  FROM pedidos   a with(nolock),  pedidos_status b with(nolock),  cadastro c with(nolock)  WHERE  a.status <> '' and  a.status=b.status and  a.id_doc = c.id_doc  and data_inclusao BETWEEN 'Test1' AND 'Test2'

Comment: What do you want now...?

Comment: OH... I wanted it to execute this: SELECT *,b.descricao as dscstatus,c.nome as cliente FROM pedidos a with(nolock), pedidos_status b with(nolock), cadastro c with(nolock) WHERE a.status <> '' and a.status=b.status and a.id_doc = c.id_doc and data_inclusao BETWEEN 'Test1' AND 'Test2' .... But since I used SELECT @SQL, it will give me the table 1x1 with that value....

Comment: i understand now.. i have to use EXECUTE@SQL instead of SELECT @SQL... or PRINT @SQL?